# The integral of the mean curvature vector over a closed immersed surface

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have a closed, orientable, smooth surface $\Sigma$ immersed smoothly in $\mathbb R^n$ via $f:\Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$.  Impose a Riemannian structure on $\Sigma$ by taking $g_{ij} = \partial_if\cdot\partial_jf$, the metric induced on $\Sigma$ by the immersion $f$.  The inner product here is just the usual inner product from $\mathbb R^n$.

The mean curvature vector is
$$
\vec H = \Delta f,
$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $(\Sigma,g)$.

Consider the integral of the mean curvature vector over the surface $\Sigma$:
$$
\int_\Sigma \vec H\ d\mu.
$$
It seems rather plausible that this ought to be zero in the case where $\Sigma$ is closed, embedded, and has only one codimension.  Is this known?  Is it easy to prove?

If it is not zero in the generality above, as a surface immersed in $\mathbb R^n$, is it equal to some expression involving topological information of $\Sigma$?

Comment: I found [this](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2031060) (paywalled) just from googling mean curvature vector.

Comment: @anon My university doesn't have a subscription to that journal, and it would be nice to see what kind of conditions they impose on $f$ and $\Sigma$ to obtain their result.

Comment: The preview shows that the authors impose the conditions closed, orientable, and $C^2$, but the paper only considers surfaces in $\mathrm{R}^3$.

Comment: @anon Since I can't see the proof, it may also be that they are assuming the surface is embedded and has genus 0.  Sometimes this went without saying.

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "Laplace-Beltrami operator on $f$"? $f$ is a function, not a Riemannian manifold. And the domain of $f$ is $\Sigma$, which you did not assume to have a Riemannian structure.

Comment: I glanced at the paper and it seems to use no further hypotheses than those mentioned by @anon. They give two methods, the second one is neat. They show that the vector-valued $2$-form given by $\vec{H}\,dA$ in has exact components, hence the integral vanishes by Stokes... They then mention that the result (maybe method?) generalizes to show for a closed $C^2$ hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^n$ one has $$\int_{\Sigma} (\operatorname{trace}\,\Omega) \vec{N}\,dA = 0$$ for the curvature $2$-form $\Omega$ and normal vector $\vec{N}$.

Comment: @Willie I meant by this that $\Sigma$ has a Riemannian structure induced by $f$.  I shall make it more explicit.

Comment: @Theo Thanks for the summary.  Exact components in which basis, the standard Euclidean basis?  I didn't think of trying that.  The generalisation you mention really answers the question I have posed.

Comment: Yes, in the standard basis.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666587/integrate-the-normal-vector-over-a-spherical-polygon/2666817#2666817) of mine. It uses Clifford/Geometric Algebra. I worked with a 2D surface with arbitrary codimension, but it easily generalizes to arbitrary dimension. The integral of the mean curvature vector over $M$ is proportional to the integral of the unit vector tangent to $M$, normal to $\partial M$, over $\partial M$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result is in fact true for arbitrary codimensions. See Lemma 2.1 in [this paper](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/63187/Documents/MypaperinAnnalidiMath.pdf). A very quick proof taken from that paper:

Let $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be some immersed submanifold. Let $X$ be a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We can decompose locally $X = X_t + X_n$ the tangential and normal componens to $\Sigma$. By definition we have that for $Y$ tangent to $\Sigma$

$$ \partial_Y X_t = \nabla_Y X_t + h(X_t,Y) $$

and

$$ \partial_Y X_n = - A_{X_n}(Y) + \nabla^\perp_Y X_n $$

where $\nabla$ is the induced Levi-Civita connection, and $\nabla^\perp$ is the induced normal connection. $h$ is the second fundamental form and $A$ is the Weingarten map associated to $X_n$: $\langle Z, A_{X_n}(Y)\rangle = \langle - h(Y,Z), X_n\rangle$

Suppose $X$ is a parellel vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$. $\partial_Y X = 0$. This implies that $\nabla_Y X_t = - A_{X_n}(Y)$. Using the definition of the Weingarten map, we have that the $g$-trace of $\nabla X_t = \operatorname{div} X_t$ is equal to $\langle H, X\rangle$. So we have that if $\Sigma$ is a closed manifold, by the divergence theorem, $\int_\Sigma \langle H,X\rangle d\mu = 0$ if $X$ is a parallel, hence constant, vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

---

One could also note the following: while the notion of $\int_\Sigma H d\mu$ is not well-defined for $\Sigma$ isometrically immersed in an arbitrary Riemannian manifold $M$, because there is no canonical vector space in which the $H$, evaluated at different points in $\Sigma$, all live. But if instead we consider the version where instead we treat $\int_\Sigma \langle H,X\rangle d\mu$, we see that for any $X$ a vector field in $M$ defined along $\Sigma$ such that $X$ is parallel along $\Sigma$, we have the same conclusion.

Comment: Hi Willie, thanks for the answer.  Could you elaborate a little more on why there is no canonical vector space in which the mean curvature of a submanifold lives?  I would have naively thought the Euclidean analogue works under mild conditions on the ambient space.

Comment: @Glen: the same reason that there is no canonical vector space in which the tangent vectors to an abstract Riemannian manifold lives. A choice of decomposition $TM = M \times V$ for some vector space $V$ would imply that (a) $M$ is parallelisable and (b) it admits a flat connection. To make sense of differential and integration, you need that this connection agree with the Levi-Civita one. Now, of course you don't need the whole $TM$ for there to be a canonical vector space associated to the normal bundle of $\Sigma$, but you'd need at very least sufficiently large parallel subbundle of $TM$.

Comment: In other words, you need a distribution $E\subset TM$ such that $E$ contains the normal bundle of $\Sigma$, and that $E$ is invariant under parallel transport *in $M$ along $\Sigma$* with **trivial holonomy**. This puts a restriction on $M$ and $\Sigma$ that I wouldn't necessarily call "mild". As an illustration: for the case of an orientable hypersurface, the normal bundle is of course trivialisable. However, it is parallel only when the second fundamental form vanishes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll have to think a bit more before I can digest this fully.

Answer (score 4):

For immersions into $R^3$ (rather than arbitrary codimension) there is basically a one-line proof:

$$2\int_\Sigma HN dA = \int_\Sigma df \wedge dN = \int_\Sigma d(fdN) = \int_{\partial\Sigma = \emptyset} f dN = 0.$$

Here $N$ is the Gauss map associated with the immersion $f: M \to \mathbb{R}^3$. The relationship $df \wedge dN = 2HNdA$ is also not hard: let $\kappa_i$ be the curvatures associated with principal directions $X_i$, so that $dN(X_i)=\kappa_i df(X_i)$.  Then

$$df \wedge dN(X_1,X_2) = df(X_1) \times dN(X_2) - df(X_2) \times dN(X_1) = (\kappa_1 + \kappa_2) df(X_1) \times df(X_2) = 2HNdA(X_1,X_2).$$

(Note that here the wedge product uses the cross product $\times$ to define an algebra on $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e., $\alpha \wedge \beta(X,Y) := \alpha(X) \times \beta(Y) - \alpha(Y) \times \beta(X)$.)

Comment: An even simpler way: constants are not in the kernel of the Laplacian;  just apply the divergence theorem: $\int_\Sigma \vec{H}\ dA = \int_\Sigma \Delta f\ dA = \int_\Sigma \nabla \cdot \nabla f\ dA = \int_{\partial\Sigma = \emptyset} N \cdot \nabla f\ dA = 0.$

Comment: Yes, I didn't come back to this question but you are right, it does follow very quickly from Stokes.